# Flattening or normalizing partial JSON records

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot record set that contains several fields that contain the same values. I will be returning this data as JSON in an HTTP response object. The common fields that are in every row (the first X fields of the records) should be unique, then the others should be returned as an array. In short, below is the before and (hopefully) after:

What I currently Have:

```
{
    "Field1":"Foo",
    "Field2":"Bar",
    "Field3":"Fizz",
    "Field4":"Buzz",
    "Field5":"John",
    "Field6":"Smith",
    "Field7":"24",
    "Field8":"Ohio"
}

{
    "Field1":"Foo",
    "Field2":"Bar",
    "Field3":"Fizz",
    "Field4":"Buzz",
    "Field5":"Michael",
    "Field6":"Jackson",
    "Field7":"38",
    "Field8":"California"
}

{
    "Field1":"Foo",
    "Field2":"Bar",
    "Field3":"Fizz",
    "Field4":"Buzz",
    "Field5":"Tim",
    "Field6":"Burton",
    "Field7":"45",
    "Field8":"New York"
}
```

What I would like to transform this data info:

```
{
    "Field1":"Foo",
    "Field2":"Bar",
    "Field3":"Fizz",
    "Field4":"Buzz",
        [
            {"Field5":"John","Field6":"Smith","Field7":"24","Field8":"Ohio"},
            {"Field5":"Michael","Field6":"Jackson","Field7":"38","Field8":"California"},
            {"Field5":"Tim","Field6":"Burton","Field7":"45","Field8":"New York"}
    ]
}
```

Is there some magical java directive or annotation that would do something like that? I'm pretty new to the language, and I've already been quite amazed about how many extremely useful built-ins there are, so I'm hoping that the magic hat has yet another rabbit in it. Of course I can write the logic manually to do the work, but if such a mechanism exists, I'm sure it would be far more performant than anything I could write.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No, I don't think there will be anything built in. It's a pretty strange use case. So if you want this, you'll have to code the objects yourself, do the mapping, then serialize to JSON.

Comment: Does "Spring Boot record set" mean you have that objects parsed, i.e. input is a List of some custom Objects?

Comment: Well it's a spring boot app that queries a database for some records, (the before diagram above) then needs to transform that into a JSON object (the after diagram).  I have a custom data type that stores it in my domain class. (Still learning a lot of the terminology since I'm very new to java.)

Comment: Are common fields set known in advance? Not exact values, but the fact that it is field1+field2+...+field4?

Comment: Yes, I know what all of the field names will be - in the example, it will always be Field1 - Field4, no more, and no less.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution, however, you can benefit from stream API and java 16 records. Btw, records can be defined even locally in any method implementation.

```
    record CommonFields(String field1, String field2, ...) {
    }
    record OtherFields(String field5, String field6, ...) {
    }

    Map<CommonFields, List<OtherFields>> groupedRecords = inputList.stream()
            .map(e -> Map.entry(new CommonFields(e.getField1(), e.getField2()), new OtherFields(e.getField5(), e.getField6())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Having such a map you can verify there is single entry and then either built a target custom object from it (could also be a record), either build a `JsonNode`. Target object and JsonNode could be serialized manually or passed to the Spring framework, usually default serialization will take place.